# Shortcuts are saved immediately to all keymap presets

Tags: customization, shortcut

**I created a new keymap preset, if I try to change something in it, the changes affect ALL other presets.**

For example: I reset all the settings to the factory settings, created a new keymap preset and named it "Test", then changed the "Pick Shortest Path" shortcut to another. When I try to switch to other keymap presets (for example, "Blender" or "Industry Compatible"), this change affects them too, how can I fix this? is this a bug?

I uploaded a video where the problem is visible, please watch this: 
[youtu.be/3LgBPfjSPGU](http://youtu.be/3LgBPfjSPGU)

Comment: Apparently this is by design, which I find very weird: https://developer.blender.org/T69991

Comment: Clearly, thanks. Do I understand correctly that this will not be fixed? Where can I report a bug?

Comment: The ticket I've linked is from the official bug tracker and Brecht is one of the core developers. This behavior of the custom keymaps is something that has to be discussed with the other developers, since it is a design decision. The bug tracker isn't the right place for these discussions, therefore I've already contacted the other developers on Blender's developer channel.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope this will be fixed in the near future, good luck.