# Blender Keymap presets - how do they work exactly?

Tags: shortcut, customization

I'm having trouble understanding the keymap presets system. I create a new keymap preset, then with that preset selected I go and edit some keys. Then I go back to the default Blender keymap but... the one I edited in my preset is also written to the Blender one? If I restore the keymap in the Blender preset then the changes I make in my preset are also restored.

A similar [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162557/shortcuts-are-saved-immediately-to-all-keymap-presets) has been asked previously to which a comment was made linking to a blender developer site that states that this is in fact by design. My question is then how are you supposed to use the preset system if every change you make is applied to all keymaps?

Am using 2.83 but have tested this behaviour is the same going all the way back to 2.79

Comment: As a workaround you can create your own custom keymaps and save them to a file (they are just a python script) use the import and export boxes at the top.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of presets if editing one edits all of them? I really do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question Arvin, but I believe there are two approaches for you:

1. Edit the entire blender default keymaps to your liking, and export the entire keymap and save it as a file via Edit >> Preferences >> Keymap >> Export

OR

2. If you intend to be able to quickly toggle on and off different modular sets of keymaps, then as @susu suggested, you may want to set up python scripts for each module of keymap modifications, which you can then toggle on or off individually from the Addons pane

[Here](https://github.com/brybalicious/toggle_mmb_numpad/blob/master/__init__.py) is an example of a script with two custom keymaps, being used as an addon to modify a custom operator, which is then available for keymap editing via the Edit >> Preferences >> Keymap pane